# Duplicating a github repo using Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am in the process of automating the duplication of multiple github repos. I would like to copy over a repo from github.com to my enterprise github using a Jenkins job.

The 3 primary commands that I need to run are

```sh
$ git clone --bare https://github.com/exampleuser/old-repository.git
$ cd old-repository.git
$ git push --mirror https://github.com/exampleuser/new-repository.git
```

github.com does not require authentication. But my enterprise github does require authentication.

My Jenkins file till now is

```sh
pipeline {
    agent { label 'master' }
    stages {
        stage('Copy repo from upstream to local github') {
          steps {
            script {
              cleanWs()
              git 'https://github.com/kubernetes/cloud-provider.git'
              sh 'ls -ltrh'
              withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'githubCloner', passwordVariable: '', usernameVariable: '')]) {
                 sh 'git push --mirror https://<URL-TO-ENTERPRISE-GITHUB>/<ORG>/ext-cloud-provider.git'
                }
            }
          }
        }

    }
}
```

The credentials Im using are username/password for a technical user who has write permissions on the internal github repo.

But im running into the below error

```sh
[Pipeline] sh
+ git push --mirror https://github.wdf.sap.corp/cx-pi-generic-pipeline/ext-cloud-provider.git
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://<URL-TO-ENTERPRISE-GITHUB>': No such device or address
```

If I switch to `ssh`, I get the error

```sh
+ git push --mirror ssh://<URL-TO-ENTERPRISE-GITHUB>/<ORG>/ext-cloud-provider.git
error: cannot run ssh: No such file or directory
fatal: unable to fork
```

The reason the second approach doesnt work is because I dont have ssh installed locally. But my issue is why doesnt the first approach work in this case ?